# Separate code from view in single PHP scripts

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller

I have an entire application written in PHP files. Each file handles operations, database access and html printing by itself. Years have gone away and I learnt about MVC, frameworks and so on. I´m about to resell this app with some improvements, most of them visual, but we are talking of almost 70 files to edit!

Is there a way to, for instance, separate each file into controller and view, so I can edit just the view in a more clear way? Also, doing so will allow me to migrate to CodeIgniter.

Comment: you could use http://www.smarty.net It's a pretty easy to use template system that will help keep the server side logic separate from the html

Comment: If you are thinking about migration then take a look at [laravel](http://laravel.com/) or [laravel4](http://four.laravel.com).

Answer (score 2):

PHP already is templating language. You should instead use what's there to create [simple templates](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html) without any fancy 3rd party tools. This will let you separate you HTML from the rest of you code.

Also, I would recommend to separate the DB interaction from you applications core logic.

If you have a working application, then do not slap a framework on top of it. Frameworks are tools that improve initial development speed. But the app is already there. Now you will only get the drawbacks of a framework, without any benefits.

As for MVC, it is an architectural design pattern. Frameworks do not implement MVC. Your code does (or doesn't). To understand MVC you at first need good understanding of OOP principles and practices (SOLID, SoC, LoD, DI). Just because you add a framework, it will not magically "add mvc" to your code. It's not some kind of sauce.

Finally, I would strongly recommend for you to stay away from CodeIgniter and CakePHP. They are the two worst frameworks in PHP. They contain a lot of bad practices, such as: global state, php4 artifacts, computation in constructors, misnaming of patterns and breaking of the separating of concerns.

They do not implement MVC or any MVC-inspired design patter, instead they are just bad Rails rewrites for PHP.

Comment: Not trying to turn this into a framework debate or anything, but I tend to think the use of CakePHP 2.x as a full stack framework is a satisfactory example of an MVC design pattern.  Earlier versions not so much.

Comment: @dcd018 Do you know what are the controller's responsibilities in the MVC design pattern? How about view instance? Look it up. And then compare it to what cake's documentation has been feeding you.

Comment: Let me rephrase, a satisfactory MVC representation because technically you're right, Cake does not treat views as objects, instead as templates leaving all display logic to the controller, at least that's my understanding.  In my humble opinion, at most it's a half decent representation of an MVC design pattern.

Comment: There is the other side too. The `AppModel` instances are just a bunch of active record implementations. Your controllers are directly dealing with interaction between those, thus forcing the "application logic" (and parts of both "domain logic" and "persistence logic") in the controllers. Cake implements some separation (akin to Rails) but it is nothing like MVC. You have templates, ORM and something the pretend to be "controller". That's not even remotely like MVC.

Comment: True, I guess one MVC'ish thing about it is the view and direct relation to the model layer.. to each his own.  Call me bias but it does make development a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

Use a template engine, look at this options:

http://www.smarty.net/

https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php

Or use a framework like codeigniter

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/